# Optimal method for retrieving two levels of hierarchical data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

There seems to be no shortage of hierarchical data questions in MySQL on SO, however it seems they are mostly talking about managing such data in the database or actually retrieving recursively hierarchical data. My situation is neither.  I have a grid of items I need to display.  Each item can also have 0 or more comments associated with it.  Right now, both the item, along with its data, are displayed in the grid as well as any comments belonging to that item.  Usually there is some sort of drill down, dialog, or other user action required to see child data for a grid item but in this case we display both parent and child data in the same grid.  Might not fit the de facto standards but it is what it is.

Right now the comments are retrieved by a separate MySQL query for every single parent item in the grid.  I immediately cringe at this being aware of all the completely separate database queries that have to be run for a single page load.  I haven't profiled but I wouldn't be too surprised if this is part of the slow page loads we sometimes see.  I'd like to ideally bring this down to a single query or perhaps 2.  However, I'm having difficulty coming up with a solution that sounds any better than what is currently being done.

My first thought was to flatten the comment children for each row with some sort of separator like '|' and then explode them back apart in PHP when rendering the page.  The issue with this is it gets increasingly complicated with having to separate each field in a  comment, and then each comment, and then account for the possibility of separator characters in the data.  Just feels like a mess to maintain and debug.

My next thought was to left outer join the comments to the items and just account for the item duplicates in PHP.  I'm working with Codeigniter's database library that returns a PHP array for database data.  This sounds like potentially a lot of duplicated data in the resulting array which could possibly be system taxing for larger result sets.  I'm thinking in most cases it wouldn't be too bad though so this option is currently at the top of my possibilities list. Ideally, if I understand MVC correctly, I should keep my database, business logic, and view/display as separate as possible.  So again, ideally, there should not be any database "quirks" (for lack of a better word) apparent in the data returned by the model. That is, whatever calls for data from this model method, shouldn't be concerned with duplicate data like this.  So I'd have to add on an additional loop to somehow eliminate the duplicate item array entries but only after I have retrieved all the child comments and placed them into their own array.

Two queries is another idea but then I have to pass numerous item IDs in the SQL statement for the comments and then go through and zip all the data together manually in PHP.

My goal isn't to get out of doing work here but I am hoping there is some more optimal (less resource intensive and less confusing to the coder) method I haven't thought of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state in your question, using a join will bring back a lot of duplicate information.  It should be simple enough to remove in PHP, but why bring it back in the first place?

Compiling a SQL statement with a list of IDs retrieved from the query for your list of items shouldn't be a problem (see [cwallenpoole's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469709/optimal-method-for-retrieving-two-levels-of-hierarchical-data-from-mysql/6470081#6470081) answer).  Alternatively, you could create a sub-query so that MySQL recreates the list of IDs for you - it depends on how intensive the sub-query is.

Select your items:

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE description = 'Item 1';
```

Then select the comments for those items:

```
SELECT * FROM comment WHERE item_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM item WHERE description = 'Item 1'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, I solve this type of problem using some sort of [ORM Lazy-Loading system](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-lazy-loading) but it does not look like you've that as an option.

Have you considered:

1. Select all top-level items.
2. Select all second-level items by the ID's in the top-level set.
3. Associate the objects retrieved in 2 with the items found in 1 in PHP.

Basically (in pseudo-code)

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT ID /*columns*/ FROM ENTRIES");
$entries = array();
foreach( $row as $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
   $row['child-entities'] = array();
   $entries[$row['id']] = $row;
}

$ids = implode(',',array_keys($entries));
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT PARENT_ID  /*columns*/ FROM children WHERE PARENT_ID IN ($ids)");

foreach( $row as $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
   $entries[$row['parent_pid']]['child-entities'][] = $row;
}
```

`$entries` will now be an associative array with parent items directly associated with child items. Unless recursion is needed, that should be everything in two queries.